# Spring Security User Information

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a quick question in regards to Spring Security and obtaining further information(Instance variables) for the current logged in `User`. By default, without the necessity to write your own `UserDetailsService` Is there a way to obtain any of the other instance variables that are defined within my `User` bean? As you're probably aware by placing the following code in one of my controllers I have access to the following fields such as: Username, password, enabled, authorities, etc.

```
UserDetails userDetails = 
               (UserDetails) ((Authentication)principal).getPrincipal();
```

I would like to obtain other information such as the following instance variables I have defined in my User object (ID, NAME, EMAIL, ETC):

```
 // Instance Variables
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private String email;
 private String username; // I can already obtain this
 private String password; // I can already obtain this
```

Could you please provide some further assistance in way which I can get more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are aware that you can get the `UserDetails` object using following code.

```
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Using UserDetails object, you can get username, password and authorities. Now you want ID and email of that user. In this case, once your user is authenticated, you can have a database query which will return you user object by username.

Answer (score 1):

Your User Object must implement UserDetails interface. When you get a reference to it cast it correctly so you can access getter methods.

Let's say your user object is like

```
public class MyUser implements UserDetails{
     private int id;
     private String name;
     private String email;
     private String username;

}
```

After succesful login you would store an instance of MyUser in as the principal.

Then

```
     MyUser userDetails = 
           (MyUser) ((Authentication)principal).getPrincipal();
     String name = userDetails.getName();
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you please provide an example of what you mean by 'When you get a reference to it cast it correctly'. That will be appreciated.